# Sending my Bitcoin cash using my private key

Tags: client, bitcoin-cash

This question has probably been answered many times but despite my efforts I cannot find a solution. I have several Bitcoin (BTC) addresses for which I hold all private keys. These addresses now also hold Bitcoin Cash (BCC) and so my question: how get I can hold of the BCC?
I have tried several BCC wallets but none allow me to import a private key...
I just want to make a transfer (to an exchange to get BTC instead) so I dont want a wallet that forces me to sync the complete chain.

Note:

- Coinomi on Android apparently allows me to import private keys, but for some reason it wont display my BCC after I try importing the key (no error message, nothing)
- To do the same with BTC I use blockchain.info, deleting all addresses after the transfer is sent

Comment: Try sweeping your BTC private keys from your Coinomi BCH wallet 'Overview' tab, by clicking .../Sweep Wallet. Note that you need to create a BCH wallet *without* altering the derivation path of the wallet (ie the derivation path of the BCH wallet you create must be M/44H/145H/0H).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few more wallets I got one to do what I want :): http://electroncash.org/

Of course it had to wait until I had already posted my question...